How would I make an agent noun out of the word "autodice -es f" or "autodicia"
I was on neolatinlexicon trying to find a word for vigilante, and I came across some words under "vigilantism, taking the law into ones own hands", which were autodice -es f and autodicia
If I wanted to say "vigilante" instead of "vigilantism", how would I make an agent noun out of this? Would it be "autodicus"?

It doesn't quite mean "vigilante", but the Greek word (these Latin words come from Greek) would be αὐτόδικος, a normal 2nd declension word.
This in turn would come into Latin as autodicus, -i, m. and autodica, -ae, f.
As a compound, the form in Greek wouldn't change regardless of whether it's masculine or feminine, although Latin tended to ignore that rule. For a parallel, the Greek word φιλόσοφος was 2nd declension regardless of whether it's applied to a masculine or feminine noun, but in Latin, you get philosophus, -i, m. for men/masculine nouns and philosopha, -ae, f. for women/female nouns, as in Cicero's letter to his brother (3.1.2): ea villa tamquam philosopha videtur esse.
